# Almost Surely Linear Combination of IID Bounded Random Variables Implies Convergence in Coefficient?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d. bounded non-constant random variables and suppose that a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ is chosen so that the series $\sum_n a_n X_n$ converges almost surely. Is it true that $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$?

I do not have the tools such as the Komogorov's three series theorem or 0-1 law. Are there any elementary way to solve this problem? My intuition is that the sum is not convergent and I am trying to get a counterexample. However, it is not easy to construct a i.i.d. bounded non-constant sequence. Any hints?

Comment: The [random harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835022/convergence-of-random-harmonic-series) likely answers your question.